# JetBrains disable auto scroll right

Tags: pycharm, horizontal-scrolling, clion, jetbrains-ide, autoscroll

I am having this problem when using JetBrains products (PyCharm, Clion, etc).

When using, for example, "Find Usage", the result window scroll to the right a bit (maybe to put the matched value in the middle).

How can I disable this kind of auto scroll ?

**Edited**:

Found a simplified version. Write in a file:

a=3; print "33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333‌​33333333333333333333‌​33333333333333333333‌​3333333" + str(a)

Then 'Find Usage' of 'a' (make sure you have set Preview as well).

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: hope this helps (http://imgur.com/a/1by5p), i just Find Usage and when the results appeared the window scrolled to the right

Answer (score 0):

Exit your IDE, delete the IDE configuration file that managed the usage view and restart your IDE. It will reset the default layout.

For PyCharm, this file is by default located here:

```
~/.PyCharm<your version>/config/options/usageView.xml
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The idea is nice, but no good. The problem is that the IDE focus the result match, and if the result is at the end of the line then the scroll will shift to the right.